# Laravel Homestead - The host path of the shared folder is missing: ~/Code

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I get this error when I try vagrant up (using last version of Homestead)

```
The host path of the shared folder is missing: ~/Code
```

here are my folders setup in .homestead/Homestead.yaml

```
folders:
    - map: c:\work\newvm\Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code
```

Of course the directory c:\work\newvm\Code exists.

Also I searched for ~/Code all over the code and it only exist in the template used for generating .homestead/Homestead.yaml ( src/subs/Homestead.yaml ).

More than that, if I remove the folder part completely I get the same error!!!

Thanks in advance, Catalin

Comment: possible duplicate of [laravel homestead the host path of shared folder missing error on windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27708326/laravel-homestead-the-host-path-of-shared-folder-missing-error-on-windows-7)

Comment: not really duplicate. I saw that answer and there the folders declaration was indeed wrong. my declaration is different. more than that, I used it in older versions of Homestead and it worked...

Answer (score 6):

I read this and wasn't quite clear on the situation, so I thought I might help clarify. If you are getting this error, pull up your console and type:

```
cd ~
mkdir Code
```

Then you can try `vagrant up` from the appropriate location again.

Answer (score 3):

Solved. 
The problem was that when running 'init.sh' git bash created the .homestead directory in my C:/Users/MyUser directory. I didn't realized that (stupid...) so I created the directory manually in my project folder. Needless to say that this folder and all my changes were ignored